# Puppeteer doesn't work well on my virtual dedicated server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, puppeteer

```
const express = require('express');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const app = express();

app.get('/instagram-media', async (req, res) => {
  const { postURL } = req.query;

  try {
    const mediaLink = await getInstagramMediaLink(postURL);
    if (mediaLink) {
      res.json({ mediaLink });
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ error: 'Media not found.' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error' });
  }
});

async function getInstagramMediaLink(postURL) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(postURL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

  const mediaElement = await page.$('article img, article video');
  if (mediaElement) {
    const mediaSrc = await page.evaluate(element => element.getAttribute('src'), mediaElement);
    if (mediaSrc) {
      await browser.close();
      return mediaSrc;
    }
  }

  await browser.close();
  return null;
}

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 5000');
});
```

I tried this api 3 different local computers and work well. But when I run this api on any server it's giving "media not found." output. I think this problem is server and tried 2 different server more and output is same nothing change. Can someone help me to figure out this?

Comment: It may sound dumb, but did you install Puppeteer on your VPS?

Comment: If I don't I can't get media not found output.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two things to check:

1. log `postURL` to make sure the value is correct
2. turn off firewalls of the server to allow http(s) outgoing traffic

Comment: I check Instagram postURL on my local computer and work well also I disabled all firewall things.